# Trouble with running cron job in GAE python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, cron

So I made a cron job to update my news aggregator app with new stories every 1 minute. I should say I'm a complete novice to cron jobs, with very limited experience running GAE.

This is my folder structure:

- news.py
- index.yaml
- feedparser.py
- cron.yaml
- app.yaml
- templates
- static

This is what's in `news.py`:

```
feed = ['https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&pz=1&ned=in&topic=e&ict=ln&output=rss&num=10']

feedlist = []

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class CronTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/entertainment')

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(render_str('mainpage.html'))

class Entertainment(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        rssfeed = feedparser.parse(feed)
        for news in rssfeed.entries:
            new_entry = {'title': news.title, 'url': news.link, 'publisheddate': news.published}
            feedlist.append(new_entry)
        self.redirect('/1/display')

class Display(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page_no):
        is_this_last = False
        list_to_be_displayed_here = feedlist[(int(page_no)-1)*5:int(page_no)*5]
        try:
            is_last = feedlist[int(page_no)*5]
        except:
            is_this_last = True
        self.response.write(render_str('/display.html', page_no=page_no, feedlist=list_to_be_displayed_here, is_this_last=is_this_last))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/entertainment', Entertainment),
                           ('/([0-9]+)/display', Display),
                           ('/crontask', CronTask)
                            ], debug = True)
```

I assume this is how `cron.yaml` is supposed to be set up:

```
cron:
- description: periodic update of news
  url: /crontask
  target: beta
  schedule: every 1 minute
```

This is app.yaml:

```
application: encoded-alpha-139800
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /crontask
  script: news.py

- url: /.*
  script: news.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

`display.html` just displays the feeds' info and since I didn't know how to implement the `cursor()` method, I implemented the rudimentary pagination that you see in `get()` of `Display`, with me slicing `feedlist`.

When I run `news.py`, I get this traceback:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
_run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 758, in start
options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 831, in __init__
module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(config_path, app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 127, in __init__
self._config_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 424, in _parse_configuration
config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 2190, in LoadSingleAppInfo

listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 227, in Parse
self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 178, in _HandleEvents
raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: news.py
  in "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\NewsAggregatorGAE\app.yaml", line 19, column 18
```

Is it because I'm trying to run almost the entire application through a cron job? Or is there something wrong with my settings, or my entire setup?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you indicated the handler to be a CGI app in your `app.yaml` file:

```
script: news.py
```

From [Request handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_Requests):

> When App Engine receives a web request for your application, it calls
>   the handler script that corresponds to the URL, as described in the
>   application's app.yaml configuration file . The Python 2.7 runtime
>   supports the WSGI standard and the CGI standard for backwards
>   compatibility. WSGI is preferred, and some features of Python 2.7 do
>   not work without it. The configuration of your application's script
>   handlers determines whether a request is handled using WSGI or CGI.
>
> ...
>
> If you mark your application as thread-safe, concurrent requests will
>   be enabled, which means that App Engine can dispatch multiple requests
>   to each web server in parallel. To do so, set threadsafe: true in
>   app.yaml. Concurrent requests are not available if any script handler
>   uses CGI.

Just make it a WSGI app and this error should go away:

```
script: news.app
```

Remember that the GAE cron service is nothing but a generator for GET requests to the configured URLs according to the configured schedule. From  [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron):

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.
>   These tasks are commonly known as cron jobs. These cron jobs are
>   automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service.
>
> ...
>
> A cron job invokes a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given time
>   of day. An cron job request is subject to the same limits as those for
>   push task queues.

How your app executes the cron jobs really boils down to how it handles those requests.

Comment: It didn't give any errors now. But it doesn't seem to automatically run. I started the server, went to  the mainpage, clicked on the link to go to `\entertainment`, the news feeds came, but then I waited for something like 3 minutes and yet the page didn't reload nor did I see any new logs.

Comment: On the development server it needs to be triggered manually. Click `Run Now` in the `Cron Jobs` page on the admin page.

Comment: So it seems `cron.yaml` isn't loaded onto the admin server. This is what I get on the `Cron Jobs` page - `EventError: Unable to assign value 'every 1 minute' to attribute 'schedule'`

Edit: Ah yes, I think I have to specify "minutes", instead of "minute".

Comment: It still fails though. `Request failured with status: 302` - I get this when going to the `Cron Jobs` page on the admin console. I tried searching and one google groups talked about `login: admin` for allowing the cron job to access admin URLs. I don't have any login or registration, but I added that under the `crontask` handler in `app.yaml`. Nothing. I even added `retry_parameters` as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#retrying_cron_jobs_that_fail). Nothing. I still get the error.

Comment: Just a question - do I have to do [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#upload-cron), by any chance? I'm already editing the yaml file in my text editor and the development server restarts on every update.

Comment: No, that only updates the cron config on the GAE deployed app. The devserver (at least the one in the linux python SDK) monitors the `cron.yaml` file changes and reloads it when needed without restarting. You do have to reload the admin page to see the changes, tho, the page doesn't auto-update. Other SDKs may behave differently, not sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows Powershell and here too, the devserver monitors the file changes and restarts if there's a change. Here too, the admin page doesn't auto-update. I've tried reloading it, going over the code dozens of times, restarting the application and server.... nothing. :(

Comment: Ah, you mean the 302. Well, your cron handler makes that redirect to `/entertainment`, no?

Comment: Yes. I want the rssfeed to run periodically. Okay, I guess the 302 explains the redirect. But why is it failing with such an awful spelling mistake for failure?